# Evaluate the value of $n$ in $\, ^{n+2} P_5=18 \times \, ^{n}P_4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose $\, ^{n+2} P_5=18 \times \, ^{n}P_4$.   How can we evaluate n?

I tried expanding it like this:

$$(n+2)(n+1)(n+0)(n-1)(n-2)=18 \cdot n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$$

Then I try multiplying all of them above, but it gets longer....and now um confused.

I thoyght of dividing the R.H.S by the L.H.S (leaving the $18$ in the R.H.S) so that I could cancel some of them out.

Not sure about it.

Comment: I could not see picture ?

Comment: @Kiara What have you tried?

Comment: The one who can see the picture can edit it ? :)

Comment: @MatthewConroy can you see the picture?

Comment: @Kiara I replaced the image with TeX.

Comment: Yes, cancel stuff, you will get a quadratic.

Comment: thank you so much @MatthewConroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matthew Conroy's suggestion in the comment is right on the nail.  Often we have some polynomial and we go to great effort to factor it.  Here we have polynomials already factored, so we should leave them alone!  We have:

$$(n+2)(n+1)(n+0)(n-1)(n-2)=18 \cdot n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$$

and we can immediately cancel the factors of $n, n-1,$ and $n-2$ from  both sides, observing along the way that $n=0,1,2$ are all trivial solutions.  The cancellation leaves us with:

$$(n+2)(n+1)=18 \cdot (n-3)$$

and *now* we should expand the polynomials and collect terms, obtaining $$n^2-15n +56 = 0$$

which we can solve by the usual methods to obtain the solutions $n=7,8$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that some terms on the left and right side of the equation will cancel.

$$\require{cancel} (n+2)(n+1)\cancel{(n+0)}\cancel{(n-1)}\cancel{(n-2)}=18 \cdot \cancel{n}\cancel{(n-1)}\cancel{(n-2)}(n-3)$$

You'll get a quadratic in $n$:

$$n^2 + 3n + 2 - 18n + 54 = n^2 - 15n + 56 = (n-7)(n-8) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

First, are there restrictions on $n$? For example, n=0,1,2 could lead to each side evaluating to zero though one could argue the 4 on the right hand side implies $n\geq4$.

$(n+2)(n+1)=18(n-3)$ is the reduced equation.

Noticing the 18 on the R.H.S. gives me the idea of trying n=7 or 8 as the first couple of ideas:

L.H.S.: $9*8 = 72 $

R.H.S.: $18*4 = 72$

Trying n=8 gives:

L.H.S.: $10*9=90$

R.H.S.: $18*5=90$

For higher n like 16,17 the terms are too different to work out. 18*17 compared to 18*13 isn't going to be equal, nor would 19*18 compared to 18*14 as these would have a factor in common here.

Thus, $n=0,1,2,$ or $7,8$ would be solutions assuming one doesn't properly put a lower bound on n.

Comment: Uhh um sorry but can I know your name? Don't mind please....

Comment: John Brock King II would be the full legal name on my birth certificate. I tend to identify myself as JB though.

Comment: Ohh okay...King II? What does that mean? ;)

Comment: My father is "John Brock King" and I'm named after him, thus I am known as "the second" which is what the Roman numeral II represents.

Comment: Wow...I like this, you know um from Bangladesh, it is not same here, looks like you're someone very popular or your dad is too popular and you're called by this name. :) It's nice.

Comment: I'm not that popular but it is how multiple people with the same name can be handled. You could look at how Popes have numbers on their names like "Pope John Paul II" as a simple example that also had the Roman numeral for 2 in it.

Comment: Yeah, got it, I like such names.

Answer (score 1):

We have $P(n+2,5) = 18 \cdot P(n,4)$, I believe. Note that $P(x,k)=\frac{x!}{(x-k)!}$ for $x,k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x>k$, so that this equation can be rewritten as $$\frac{(n+2)!}{((n+2)-5)!}=\frac{(n+2)!}{(n-3)!}=(n+2)(n+1) \cdot n(n-1)(n-2) \\= 18 \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-4)!}=18 \cdot n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3).$$
Note from here that $n=0,1,2$ are trivial solutions (substituting these result in $0=0$). Thus, we have (for $n \neq 0,1,2,3$) $$\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{n-3}=18.$$
This should give you a good start.  Rearrange this and collect like terms to obtain a polynomial equation that you can solve for $n$.